# Magento 2 - Importing prices for multiple store views using Magmi

Tags: magento2, price, magmi

I am trying to update prices using Magmi on 2 store views but I am having issues. Here is my setup.

- store,sku, price
- abc, 1001, 5.00
- bab, 1001, 7.00

It worked perfectly.

**The question is:**

> Now I use two lines to make it clear to magmi that there are two
>   different prices. Is there a way to get the same result by writing in
>   a single line?